# SharePoint Online Drag and Drop trying to copy from Sharepoint Library to computer or hardrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, document

If i drag and drop from a SharePoint library to Windows Explorer(desktop), file is moving instead it is not copying from the library and Users are trying to drag and drop in to their hard drive they do not want to use "Download" option. I think it is a out of the box feature but it is not working for some of the libraries. The libraries which are Synced in OneDrive for those libraries the feature is not working. Is there any way we can achieve users requirement ?

Comment: Have you tried holding down Ctrl as you drag and drop?

Comment: @jason No i will try.