# Cannot drag file from SharePoint Online and drop onto local Desktop? (Windows 11 / Edge)

Tags: sharepoint-online, download, drag-and-drop

Our users are unable to drag and drop a file from SharePoint Online to their local desktop.

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

As seen in the screenshot, when the file is clicked, then dragged outside of MS Edge, the cursor icon changes indicating "Drop" is unavailable.

The following article addresses the issue in older versions of Windows, using Internet Explorer however, I am looking for a solution for Windows 11 (with Edge).

[Drag-and-drop DOWNLOAD from SharePoint to PC](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214737/drag-and-drop-download-from-sharepoint-to-pc)

Specifically, in the article, the solution proposes the following:

- Use Internet Explorer
- Make sure the site is in Trusted Sites
- Make sure Drag and drop is enabled in Trusted Sites Zone security settings
- Make sure Allow programmatic clipboard access is enabled in Trusted
  Sites Zone security settings.
- Close IE and re open it. Navigate to document library Hold Ctrl down left click document and drag to desktop and drop it.

I have tried the above steps (Ignoring the part about using IE) however, that did not help.

Other things I have tried which didn't help:

- Hold "Ctrl" when dragging the file
- Use Chrome
- Use Firefox
- Set the trusted site security settings to most permissive

Answer (score 0):

Except that you can drag file from SharePoint Online and drop onto local Desktop in IE browser, this function is not supported in other browsers. For example, the "Open with explorer" function can only be used in the IE browser.
If you want Microsoft to implement it in SharePoint Online, you can submit new idea on [SharePoint Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Answer (score 0):

Just started having this issue myself. Check your ActiveX Controls - specifically the SharePoint DragDownload Control.